# Mysql query is not sorting according to name

Tags: mysql

I am sorting a table based on the name column, but it is not sorting properly.

It is sorting like this :- First 20 rows based on alphabetical order and after that it is again sorting based on alphabetical order.

This is my query

```
select Name,ID from tbl_book order by Name Limit 0,100
```

and this is what i am getting

```
abcd|2
bgry|3
...
...
zref|100
agtr|4
dret|10
...
...
```

any one know why this is happening.

**UPDATE**

```
ID int(11)
Name varchar(255)
```

Its answer is

```
select ltrim(Name),ID from tbl_book order by 1 Limit 0,100
```

Given By TUXUDAY..

Comment: Is that the actual data? Maybe you got case sensitive sorting, first all capitals, then the lowercase beginletters.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com I guess it would be good to take a look anyway. You're right.

Comment: apart from case issue, there seems to be none.

Comment: there is no uppercase data in name column..

Comment: maybe there are leading spaces before certain names.

Comment: @YogiYogesh it is about column names, not row content

Comment: I seriously doubt that this was your original table & query.

Comment: can you try `select ltrim(Name),ID from tbl_book order by 1 Limit 0,100
`

Comment: @tuxday this will not tell the reason. I'd rather do: `select CONCAT('"', Name, '"') from tbl_book order by 1 Limit 0,100` to see what is really there.

Comment: @YogiYogesh show your **real** output data, not "abc", "def"

Comment: @tuxuday  thanks for your query. Problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT Name, ID 
FROM  tbl_book
ORDER BY LTRIM(Name)
LIMIT 100;
```

or there could be a problem with collation of data. try this also:

```
SELECT Name, ID 
FROM  tbl_book
ORDER BY LTRIM(Name) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci 
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: giving error for latin1_swedish_ci  and name column's collation was latin1_swedish_ci , i changed it to utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Try with `LTRIM` also can you check collation of `name` column with query `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tbl_book`?

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
select name,id from tbl_book orderby name asc
```

But if you want to put the limit then you you need to update the start value and put the limit value as constant like (100,20),(100,40),...

Comment: Coming..??you need to provide the same column names as at the time of creating the table

Comment: i placed name in place of Name

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
SELECT Name,ID FROM tbl_book ORDER by Name ASC LIMIT 0,100
```